# Is there any difference between UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton and UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have created a method `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`
for `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton`.

Now I want to use `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator` in place of `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton`.

Is there any difference between `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton` and `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton`?

Answer (score 6):

Apple HIG suggests that you use `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator` to navigate through hierarchical data, and `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton` to perform some action, possible bringing up an edit view, that may change the data.  However, most programmers seem to ignore this.

You can implement the delegate method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Or vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

There is difference. *UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton* is actually a button but *UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator* is not.

You can use *UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator* instead of *UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton* but you can not get the *tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:* method called when you tap on the *UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator* as it is not a button.

Comment: how can i call tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: method by using UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator ???...or how can i use custom button on UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton so that it can perform action by tapping on it..??

Comment: Create a button with target/action and assign it as accessory view. Omit the tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: method.

Comment: can you please explain it??,...how can i add button on UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton ???..

Comment: And [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851498/how-to-add-a-button-without-using-custom-cell-on-a-uitableview)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they're different.

Use `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton` when the user tapping the blue button performs a different action than tapping the rest of the row, even if the rest of the row does nothing.

Use `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator` when the entire row is tappable and produces the same action.

If your behaviour is something else, use some other mechanism.